# Javascript : Append text into div?

Tags: javascript, html

I want use javascript to append clock into inside of a div. Here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function makeArray() {
for (i = 0; i<makeArray.arguments.length; i++)
this[i + 1] = makeArray.arguments[i];
}

var months = new makeArray('January','February','March','April','May',
'June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var yy = date.getYear();
var year = (yy < 1000) ? yy + 1900 : yy;

var timer = document.write(months[month]+ " " +day + ", " + year);
document.getElementById('time').appendChild(timer);
//]]></script>

<div id='time'></div>
```

But it doesn't work. Help me for fixing it. Thanks you.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: Working fine http://jsfiddle.net/5Khyc/

Comment: copy paste the error if any

Comment: Learn how to use DOM functions, don't use `document.write()`. It overwrites the page rather than inserting into it.

Comment: "Doesn't work is doesn't work". Don't ask with your uppity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth();
var yy = date.getFullYear();
var year = (yy < 100) ? yy + 1900 : yy;

var timer = document.createElement('div');
timer.innerHTML = months[month] + " " + day + ", " + year;
document.getElementById('time').appendChild(timer);
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/H5Qp4/64)**

Answer (score 3):

**innerHTML** can write text into the div as you are not appending any element here.

```
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = months[month]+ " " +day + ", " + year;
```

for refernece :http://jsfiddle.net/SpgMm/2/

if you really want to use appendChild better use createElement and then append it to div.

Hope it helps

P.S. use this only when dealing with raw javascipt  otherwise Jquery html method is best option.

Comment: use this only when dealing with raw javascipt  otherwise Jquery html method is best option.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this will help you

```
var months = new Array('January','February','March','April','May',
'June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var yy = date.getYear();
var year = (yy < 1000) ? yy + 1900 : yy;
var timer = months[month]+ " " +day + ", " + year;
$('#time').html(timer);
```

Or in Javascript you can write as

```
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML=timer;
```

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/znbHP/1/)

Comment: This is with `jQuery`, wich is not tagged in the post... Good to name that in your answer.

Comment: It's not difficult to convert on java script @Sergio

Comment: @Subhash, do that then. Or write somewhere you have jQuery.

Comment: I write it in javascript