# how do you add text to a tag in js using innertext and add to an id of a div?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an element in js and I want to add text using innertext and add it to a div with an id how would I do this?

html

```
  <div id="divone">
</div>
```

js

```
var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript : Append text into div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197140/javascript-append-text-into-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var h1 = document.createElement('h1');

h1.innerText = "ABC";

document.getElementById('divone').appendChild(h1);
```

```html
<div id="divone"></div>
```

1. Just create h1
2. appendChild to div.

   var h1 = document.createElement('h1');

   h1.innerText = "ABC";

   document.getElementById('divone').appendChild(h1);

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by using the append child function

```
var example = document.getElementById('divone');
var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
h1.innerText = "hi";
example.appendChild(h1);
```

Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/1fh3pht7/)